# Calling mysqldump from VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to save a MySQL database from Visual Basic.  My code follows below.

I get an error message: File not Found.  Which file is not found and what am I doing wrong?

```
Private Sub Backup_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBackup.Click

    Dim StrBackup As String
    Dim strUser As String = "root"
    Dim strPass As String = "mysql"
    Dim strDbName As String = "components"
    Dim strPath As String = "c:\data"
    Dim newDBName As String = "DataBackup.sql"

    StrBackup = "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqldump.exe --host=localhost --user='" & strUser & "'   --password=mysql """ & strDbName & """  -r """ & strPath & newDBName & """"
    MsgBox(StrBackup)
    Process.Start(StrBackup)
```

Comment: Well the first thing that stuck out to me was that you have strPath & newDBName which is concatenating to c:\dataDataBackup.sql.  You at least need to add a "\" in there, so strPath & "\" & newDBName.  Or add the "\" to strPath.

Answer (score 0):

Check matching quotes, slashes and make sure all values with spaces are escaped properly. For example:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqldump.exe..."
```

Probably needs to be:

```
"'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqldump.exe'..."
```

Or better use a different overload of [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Process.Start("C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqldump.exe", arguments)
```